# JS/Lodash - Group values which occur more than once?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array something like:

```
const arr = [
  { id: 123, parent: [345] },
  { id: 811, parent: [456] },
  { id: 987, parent: [876] },
  { id: 811, parent: [137] },
  { id: 811, parent: [825] }
]
```

An object with id `811` occurs 3 times.

I need to transform it into:

```
const newArr = [
  { id: 123, parent: [345] },
  { id: 811, parent: [456, 137, 825] },
  { id: 987, parent: [876] }
]
```

That is, I need to find the objects that have an id which occurs more than once, then merge those objects into one object which has a parent array of the parent values from all the objects.

What's the best way to do this using lodash methods..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lodash, groupBy the `id`, merge each group, and concat the arrays:

```js
const arr = [{"id":123,"parent":[345]},{"id":811,"parent":[456]},{"id":987,"parent":[876]},{"id":811,"parent":[137]},{"id":811,"parent":[825]}];

const result = _(arr)
  .groupBy('id')
  .map((group) => _.mergeWith({}, ...group, (o1, o2) => 
    Array.isArray(o1) ? o1.concat(o2) : undefined
  ))
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or using ES6 you do the same thing with `Array#reduce` and `Map`:

```js
const arr = [{"id":123,"parent":[345]},{"id":811,"parent":[456]},{"id":987,"parent":[876]},{"id":811,"parent":[137]},{"id":811,"parent":[825]}];

const result = [...arr.reduce((map, obj) => {
  const group = map.get(obj.id) || { id: obj.id, parent: [] };
  
  group.parent.push(...obj.parent);
  
  return map.set(obj.id, group);
}, new Map()).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce()` method in plain js to do this, you just need to keep track of object id's and you can use another object for that.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 123, parent: [345] },
  { id: 811, parent: [456] },
  { id: 987, parent: [876] },
  { id: 811, parent: [137] },
  { id: 811, parent: [825] }
]

var o = {}
var result = arr.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if(!o[e.id]) o[e.id] = e, r.push(o[e.id])
  else o[e.id].parent.push(...e.parent)
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```